# iOS - stringByRemovingPercentEncoding returns nil for single/double quotes

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsstring, nsdata, urlencode

I have a URLRequest that comes from a UIWebView delegate (shouldStartLoadRequest) and i convert that into a NSData object. After that I convert it to a NSString of which you have something like this:

> test%22%3A%22Whats+going+on%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22

but of course now i need to get rid of all these percent sequences. My problem seems to be that if i am dealing with single quotes(%92) or double quotes(%94) the method stringByRemovingPercentEncoding returns nil. That doesn't seem to be the case for other special characters like $, ^, & , (, ), *, #.

Here is the sample code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

NSData *data = request.HTTPBody;
NSString* myString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


myString = [[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "]stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];

}
```

So what's going on with the single quotes and double quotes here? What should I do to prevent this method from returning nil??

Comment: Are you sure you're getting that string from `data`? Quick test with `NSString *myString = @"test%22%3A%22Whats+going+on%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22";` and then running your next statement gives me a string of `test":"Whats going on"}},{"`

Comment: yeah i just gave you a subset of everything I am getting as an example and to explain my issue with single quotes/double quotes

Comment: Well, since the example you provided ***does*** work, I guess you need to provide an example that ***doesn't*** work to get help...

Comment: test%22%3A%22What%92s+going+on%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22  please reference this table:https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: %92 / %94 i thought were single quotes/double quotes respectively (from an iPad keypad). not sure what %27 / %22 are supposed to be

Comment: after looking at it some more, it looks like the 'single quote' / 'double quote' on an iPad is the %92/%94 vs a laptop keypad?? i.e. %22 / %27? not sure why that method has a hard time with the first example. keep in mind, this is coming from a webview - so im assuming the data being sent to that delegate method is the result of some javascript stuff

Comment: OK - percent encoding only goes up to `%7F` ... so anything greater than that - such as `%92` or `%94` - are "invalid encodings" and as a result the method returns nil.

Comment: @DonMag so is the webview that sends the original data not parsing it right (i assume javascript?). Why is the iPad keypad returning %92 and not a single quote like on a mac as %27?. Also do you have a reference to that being invalid encodings?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8082282?answerId=32350504022#32350504022  @DonMag i just found this .. what in the world???

Comment: Ah... I just took a look at the w3schools link you posted. The double-quote character you're looking at is the "Closing Curly Quote" ... and the `%94` value on that page is under the `Windows-1252` column. If you use the value from the `UTF-8` column `%E2%80%9D` in your string, `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` *will* return (be decoded into) a valid string with that character. And `%E2%80%99` will return (be decoded into) the "Closing / Curly Single Quote" character. I couldn't tell you why the web view / javascript is not encoding it properly.

Comment: @DonMag it looks like this issue was resolved at least for 11.2.6 or 11.4. Looks like the 'smart punctuation' knows when to use the ASCII characters and when to use the other ones. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208067

Comment: please note that with the 11.4 update you dont have to turn off smart punctuation is General->Settings->Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

i am marking this as resolved. Please take a look at these references:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/89706
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8082282